Can a cyclogyro autorotate in an engine-out emergency?
A plane without a propeller is a glider.
A helicopter without it's engine can also glide. It's like a falling maple seed, except that a significant forward velocity is needed to keep the descent rate safe.
What about a cyclogyro? This kind of craft tilts it's propeller sideways. It employs cyclic pitch control using a swash plate of sorts. Such a design has noise and maneuverability advantages. If the engine is lost but control is maintained, can it glide to a soft landing?
I would think so given that it could turn into a vertical wind turbine and keep itself spinning. As long as the pilot reacted appropriately. But can it do so in a way that preserves gliding lift?

"A plane without a propeller is a glider."   Hmmm... I may have more glider time than I realized!

@RalphJ what do you fly

@RalphJ let me guess: Jet Pilot? :)

@kruemi Which are apparently also considered gliders now! (See comments on this answer for substantiation.)

Hm, jetliners these days are propeller craft in disguise: The bulk of the thrust coming from the fan pushing bypass air instead of the hot exhaust gasses.

In short
A cyclogyro, like this example from Wikipedia:

can perform an autorotated descent with engines out, according to theory and tests made on models by Carl Bruno Strandgren, one of the pioneers in the domain, and apparently the first one to file a patent for a feathering paddle wheel in 1933.

Details
Strandgren, a swedish inventor who also invented the roller screw, researched a rotating wing for several years, which he presented in a French publication in 1933.
The article was translated and presented before NACA in November 1933:

This report provides a description of the Standgren flying machine which consists of two wheels with a certain number of equidistant blades arranged around the horizontal axis of rotation and parallel to this axis. Each blade is fixed so as to be able to feather about an axis parallel to its span at the same time as it turns about the general axis of rotation.

The author explains, by calculation and experimentation on models at the Institut Aérotechnique de Saint-Cyr, the aircraft allows autorotation at any descent angle, including vertically, when properly controlled.

A system of controls permits feathering or change of incidence of the blades to conform to the desired effect: hovering, lift and propulsion combined, gliding descent, vertical descent in autorotation, etc. (Source: NACA.)


Descent with engine stopped should not present any difficulty - no more than landing - which can be effected at any inclination, including the vertical. (Source: NACA.)

A full scale aircraft was then built by Lioré & Olivier:



(Source: NACA)
The idea led to more patents (e.g. from Platt and Laskowitz) and tests at MIT and at Langley field, but it was not developed further until recent years.
A modern study, in 2009, Review of Historic and Modern Cyclogyro Design, stated:

The cycloidal rotor has mathematically and experimentally been deemed capable of autorotation. This phenomenon is very important to the safety of helicopter flight, and may help to ensure the safety of cyclogyro flight.

